# Can't get Google API key even after entering MD5 key

Tags: android, google-maps, md5

I am facing a problem as under:

I have configured out the MD5 key from jdk6 but can not get the Google API key even after entering it at  http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

Previously i was doing it through sdk7 which was producing SHA key i guess.

Comment: Plz if someone can help me out, would be very thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

You should the MD5 hash for the keystore you intend to use to sign your app.

While developing, you should use the key for the debug.keystore, which is the default keystore installed with the Android SDK.